# Is it possible to move computers between two domains (with same names)?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain

I have two networks with one domain on each. These networks are located in the same buildings but computers are used by two differents organizations that use two differents domains.

Would it be possible to take a computer from one network, and connect it to another?

What about the renaming of the domains, the computer/domain relationships, and the possibility to synchronize computers and users objects between AD, throught Internet connections?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to establish a trust relationship between the two domains to allow the computer to access resources within the other domain.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* move a computer between domains, but it would lose access to all resources in its original domain, and users from that domain would be unable to log on to it.

If you need to move users and computers between the two networks, and/or if you need to share resources between the two domains, your best option is establishing a [trust relationship](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961481.aspx) between them. This is quite easy to do, but has security implications, and it requires connectivity between the two networks.